# Wordpress Custom Tax for CPT Paging 404?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy, custom-wordpress-pages

I have googled this issue for the last 4 days, and everything I have found has not fixed the issue.

My Custom Post Type's Custom Taxonomy template paging 404's unless I set the sites Blog posts per page to 1, which I cannot do, due to the fact that there will be a need to show more than 1 "blog post" per page...

How can I correct this issue?

**LATEST FIX ATTEMPT**

```
    // fix the paging 404's on category/tag pages
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $qry ) {
        $_num_per_page = ( get_option( 'gyokb_option_name' )['gyokb_articles_pp'] ) ?? 5;
        if( ( is_tax( 'kb_categories' ) || is_tax( 'kb_tags' ) ) && ! is_admin() ) {
            $qry->set ( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'gyo_kb' ) ); 
            $qry->set( 'posts_per_page', $_num_per_page );
        }
    } );
```

My CPT is here... (too much code to paste here...)
https://pastebin.com/SyKJwnCH

My Taxonomy is here...
https://pastebin.com/4BWWgGWq

And My Paging in the template:

```
<?php 
echo paginate_links( array(
        'format' => 'page/%#%', 
        'prev_text'=>' Previous ', 
        'next_text'=>' Next ', 
        'current' => max( 1, $page ), 
        'total' => $pg_ct, 
        'type' => 'plain', 
        'mid_size' => 4, 
        'paged' => $page, ) );
?>
```

with my `WP_Query` pulling it all together....

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'gyo_kb', 'posts_per_page' => $_num_per_page, 'paged' => $page, 
               'orderby' => 'date','order' => 'DESC',
               'tax_query' => array(
                    array (
                        'taxonomy' => 'kb_categories',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $cur_cat -> slug,
                    )
                ),
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

`$page` is populated with: `$page = get_query_var( 'page' ); $page = ( ! empty( $page ) ) ? $page : 1;`

All other variables are populating properly

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying that unless you have one post per page, the pagination is leading a 404 page?

Comment: 'Settings' -> 'Reading' -> 'Blog pages show at most'.  If I set that to 1, then the paging links work as they should.   I reset it back to the default 10, and my "pages" throw a 404 instead

Comment: I can only determine that it has something to do with the Permalinks...

Comment: I got it working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the fix applying during the incorrect "boot" timing for wordpress.  Initially I had placed in in the "wp" action.

I moved it to the "init" action, and now it works.